# CSS table-cell and overflow DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in Firefox with table cell and a DIV with overflow auto on it. Here is my markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="category">
        <div id="row">
             <div id="refine">
                   <div class="content">
                        <!-- contains content -->
                   </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

#category { 
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#row {
    display: table-row;
}

#refine {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content p {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've applied a max-height on the container - and all the child elements have 100% height of the container. In the above, `.content` needs to be scrollable once the content exceeds the max-height of its parent.

In Chrome this works as expected - a scrollbar is displayed on `.content`. However in Firefox and IE, the table cell simply expands down - it does not seem to respect the max-height setting of the container.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/LpzEM/6/ (try this in Firefox and Chrome).

By the way I am unable to change the base structure of the site - so it needs to still use display table, etc.

Comment: I think firefox is confused with nesting a `display: table` directly inside another `display: table`.  Also, I think it wants the overflow to be on the element that has the max-height set.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/LpzEM/11/

Comment: Aah that works, except I can't have it on the container as that means the whole container will be scrollable rather than the inner DIV.

Comment: Can you set that max-height on the inner div?

Comment: I can.. but I was hoping it would just inherit automatically so that it would work for any screen size.

Comment: I might be missing something, but would it be any different to declaring it on the container?  I mean in terms of screen size, you want the height to be 100% and the max-height to be 200px.  Does it make a difference on a small device which element sets that? http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/LpzEM/14/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `.content` overflow to scroll.

```
.content {
    // ...
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This worked for me in Firefox on your JSFiddle.

See also http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: @LaszloPapp - Agreed. I've added a little more.

Answer (score 1):

try below code.. it works for chrome,firefox and latest internet explorer. In old internet explorer it doesn't support some css features.

```
<style>
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#container {
display: block;
width: 500px;
max-height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
}

#category { 
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#row {
    display: table-row;
}

#refine {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.content p {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="category">
        <div id="row">
             <div id="refine">
                   <div class="content">
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p><p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem iPsum</p>
                   </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't have overflow scroll on the container.